# Creating dynamic ListModel is QML

Tags: qt, qml

I've been trying to populate a ListView in QML with data from a list I have, but in the documentation it doesn't show how to dynamically populate a ListModel or ListView. The data in the list keeps changing and I intend to update the list in real time and that is why I don't have to have a hard-coded model.

Based on tutorials, this works:

```
        Rectangle {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            color: "black"
            height: 500
            width: 0.95 * parent.width
            ListView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: fruitModel
                delegate: fruitDelegate
            }
        }

        ListModel {
            id: fruitModel
            ListElement {
                name: "Apple"
                cost: 2.45
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Orange"
                cost: 3.25
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Banana"
                cost: 1.95
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: fruitDelegate
            Row {
                spacing: 10
                Text { text: name; color: "white" }
                Text { text: '$' + cost; color: "white" }
            }
        }
```

But this doesn't:

```
userModel : ["Tony", "Stark"] //list containing names of users
Rectangle {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            color: "black"
            height: 500
            width: 0.95 * parent.width
            ListView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: userModel // a list containing all users
                delegate: fruitDelegate
            }
}

Component {
            id: fruitDelegate
            Row {
                spacing: 10
                Text { text: name; color: "white" }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles define how to access the information, for example fruitModel has 2 roles: name and cost. But when using a list as a model then you have to use `modelData` as a role to access the information:

```
Component {
    id: fruitDelegate
    Row {
        spacing: 10
        Text { text: modelData; color: "white" }
    }
}
```

---

The ListModel can be updated through the [`append`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method) function:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    color: "black"
    height: 500
    width: 0.95 * parent.width
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: fruitModel
        delegate: fruitDelegate
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: fruitModel
    Component.onCompleted: {
        fruitModel.append({"name": "Tony"})
        fruitModel.append({"name": "Stark"})
    }
}

Component {
    id: fruitDelegate
    Row {
        spacing: 10
        Text { text: name; color: "white" }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an issue with using Component.onCompleted, if the list updates, the new list is not displayed, but the one which existed during instantiation. How could we solve this? Would using a Loader with a separate component instead help?

Comment: @EvanKrause I don't know how you update the list so my demo is generic. If you have other problems then create a new post giving details where you indicate how you update the list. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Okay I added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69092223/how-do-i-dynamically-update-a-listview-in-qml
Thank you for all your help!